# JS (node.js) - If I make an asynchronous call but do not wait for it to complete will it be guaranteed to complete execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Title is long question but if I make an asynchronous call in javascript but do not have a call back or chain it in a promise will it complete execution? i.e. If I have code like:

```
function markAsInactive(userId) {
    return retrieveUser(userId) // 
    .then(res => {
       const mark = markAsInactive(userId) // returns a promise (say takes 2 seconds)
       return Promise.resolve('blah')
    })
    .then(...etc)
    .catch(...)
}
```

The call to `markAsInactive` is fired but the thread does not wait for it to resolve and instead will move on to the next `then` immediately (is my understanding). Would it be guaranteed to complete execution or would the thread/process cancel the call if the stack returns back to the root?

I know that I can use something like `return Promise.all([mark, ...])` to have multiple promises resolve in parallel; this question is more for my edification.

Comment: Think of it this way: once the request was successfully made (e.g. sent to the server) it doesn't matter if you wait for a response or not, the request was sent and the server will do what it has to do and only after that it will try to respond with the result. By not "waiting" for it to complete, you are simply not catching the response.

Comment: No, for instance, it would not complete if your computer crashed, or a meteor struck the earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be guaranteed to complete execution or would the thread/process cancel the call if the stack returns back to the root?

It completes the call. **All** asynchronous operations end up exiting the current job (task) before further work on them is done, completely unwinding the stack; it's intrinsic to the [job-based nature of JavaScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) on a given thread (and NodeJS uses a single thread) and the fact that promise `then` callbacks are guaranteed to be asynchronous.

The work wouldn't be completed if NodeJS terminated before it was done, but NodeJS keeps running while there are any outstanding tasks, I/O operations, etc.